# Is there a way to reuse in place validation of Hibernate's implementation of Bean Validation at runtime?

Tags: bean-validation, hibernate-validator

For example, I have got a class:

```
@Getter
@Setter
class Notification {

  private String recipient;
  private Channel channel;

  enum Channel {
    SMS, EMAIL
  }
}
```

I could define my own Validator, for instance:

```
@Target(TYPE)
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = {RecipientValidator.class})
@interface ValidRecipient {
  // required arguments of validation annotation
}

class RecipientValidator implements ConstraintValidator<ValidRecipient, Notification> {

  @Override
  public void initialize(ValidRecipient annotation) {
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isValid(Notification value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
    boolean result = true;

    if (value.getChannel() == SMS) {
      return matches(value.getRecipient(), "<phone-number-regexp>");
    }

    if (value.getChannel() == EMAIL) {
      // can I reuse Hibernate's Email Validation there?
      return matches(value.getRecipient(), "<email-regexp>");
    }

    return result;
  }
}
```

Of course I can google regexp of email and copy-paste there but Hibernate's Bean Validation implementation already has the Email Validation (under [@Email](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/beanvalidation/spec/2.0/api/) annotation).
Is there a way to reuse that validation implementation in my custom validator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no official way to reuse a validator in another one.

What you can do though would be to initialize an `EmailValidator` attribute in `initialize()` and call its `isValid()` method in your `isValid()` method.

Keep in mind that `EmailValidator` is internal so it might be subject to changes in the future.